# Solutions of the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations in the plane

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, gauge-theory

Is there any reference describing the analytical properties of the critical points of the functional 
$$
E(\phi,A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{2}|(\partial_j-iA_j)\phi|^2+\frac{1}{4}F_{jk}F_{jk}+\frac{\lambda}{8}(1-|\phi|^2)^2
$$
with $F_{jk}=\partial_jA_k-\partial_kA_j$ (i.e. solutions of the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations)?

All that I found in the literature is related to (much) more general cases. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By critical points, do you mean computing the first variation?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I mean the couples $(\phi,A)$ for which $DE(\phi,A)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this 2D model, the system is often called the Ginzburg-Landau system, as it was introduced independently as a model of superconductors by Ginzburg and Landau.  There is a large literature devoted to this problem, so I will just mention a couple books you might find useful.  The first three consider the more general problem but have sections related to the 2D model.  The latter three specialize to the 2D case.

1. Manton and Sutcliffe, *Topological Solitons*
2. Jaffe and Taubes, *Vortices and Monopoles*
3. Yang, *Solitons in Field Theory and Nonlinear Analysis*
4. Bethuel, Brezis, and Helein, *Ginzburg-Landau Vortices*
5. Pacard and Riviere, *Linear and Nonlinear Aspects of Vortices*
6. Sandier and Serfaty, *Vortices in the Magnetic Ginzburg-Landau Model*

Comment: Thank you, I checked Yang's book and it's really useful! One question: isn't the Ginzburg-Landau system the particular case in which $A=0$?

Comment: I guess that's more of a matter of who you ask.  The original system proposed by G-L has $A$ playing the role of the magnetic vector potential, and $F$ playing the role of the magnetic field.  When one ignores these some people call the resulting system the "simplified" or "non-magnetic" G-L system, but some people just say G-L for the simplified system and "magnetic" G-L for the original problem.  The latter naming convention is in use with references 4-6.  The problem without mag. field is of independent interest in the theory of harmonic maps and their relaxations.